# Unresolved external symbol for statically build zlib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, zlib

I'm on VS2022. I'm creating a little static library to handle embedded resources (so let's call it `er`) in my c++ project.

This library uses `zlib` (latest version, 1.3.1) to compress the files before processing it (details don't really matter here). So I built zlib and linked my `er` project against `zlibstaticd.lib` and `zlibstatic.lib`.

The cmake file is something like:

```
set (EXPORT_HEADER_FILES
    export/er/er.hpp
)
set (SOURCE_FILES
    cpp/er.cpp
)

source_group("er/cpp" FILES ${SOURCE_FILES})
source_group("er/export" FILES ${EXPORT_HEADER_FILES})

add_library(er STATIC ${EXPORT_HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(ZLIB_LIBS 
    debug ${ZLIB_LIBRARY}/zlibstaticd.lib optimized ${ZLIB_LIBRARY}/zlibstatic.lib
)

target_link_libraries(er PRIVATE ${ZLIB_LIBS})

target_include_directories(er
    PRIVATE hpp ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    PUBLIC export
)
```

Everything's fine so far.

Now, the point is I want `er` to be standalone, that's why `zlib` is linked **privately**. There is no mention of `zlib` in the `er.hpp` file.

So now I build `er`, and want to use it in my other project (`lib2` let's call it).

So I add `er` and link it as static lib to my project (just like I did with zlib for `er`). But when I try to compile I now get linkers errors as follows:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol inflate referenced in function "bool __cdecl er::decompress(...)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol deflate referenced in function "bool __cdecl er::compress(...)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol deflateEnd referenced in function "bool __cdecl er::compress(...)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol inflateEnd referenced in function "bool __cdecl er::decompress(...)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol deflateInit_ referenced in function "bool __cdecl er::compress(...)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol inflateInit_ referenced in function "bool __cdecl er::decompress(...)
```

Now why would I get that? `inflate`, `deflate`, `deflateEnd`, `inflateEnd`,... Those are `zlib` functions and as I don't want to link `zlib` to `lib2`.

I'm really lost here. I tried the

```
#define ZLIB_WINAPI
#include <zlib/zlib.h>
```

in the `er.cpp` file like some can mentions in some answers I found on SO, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Static libraries are nothing more than archives of object files. They are not linked like applications are. Therefore when you link with a static library, you also need to link with all other libraries that they depend on.

Comment: is it for linux or windows?

Comment: you need to compile the lib into static lib , do U use makefile, or visual studio to build ?

Comment: @mayacohen on Windows, I build zlib with visual studio, I already set everything as static.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Do you mean that static libraries cannot embbed other static libraries?
Dlls can though right?

Comment: A DLL is very much like a stand-alone program, and built the same way. Static libraries aren't linked at all, you just create a set of object file, and put them together in an archive (similar to an uncompressed zip-file). However, there are properties on the library target you can set in CMake to add other libraries as dependencies, and CMake will create build-instructions to also link with those dependencies. I don't remember which property, but you can browse [the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html) to find more information, and do some experiments.

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that's why zlib is linked privately.

As Some programmer dude commented, archive libraries are *not* linked in any sense of the word.

You can think of them as a shopping bag filled with object files. You want to prepare a baked potato with sour cream; you have potatoes in one shopping bag (`er.lib`) and sour cream in another (`zlib.lib`). When preparing the meal, you need to use *both* bags (at link time), i.e. link your final program with both `er.lib` and `zlib.lib`.

You *could* put all of your ingredients into a single shopping bag, and then you would only need that one shopping bag (the combined `erz.lib`) at link time.

To do that, you can unpack `er.lib` and `zlib.lib` to extract all the `.obj` files from them, and add these object files into the combined `erz.lib` library.

**Update:**

> is there an automatic way to do it? I mean like a build rule or a cmake function?

I don't know about `cmake` function, but you can trivially construct a `Makefile` rule for it. It turns out that (unlike UNIX `ar`) `LIB.EXE` can directly combine `.LIB` files in a single command:

```
LIB.EXE /OUT:erz.lib er.lib zlib.lib
```

Comment: Thanks. About the part where we extract `.obj` files and combine them, is there an automatic way to do it? I mean like a build rule or a cmake function?